# dotnet Core Authentication OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client' after OneLogin

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, openid-connect, onelogin

I followed the OneLogin dotnet setup steps from the OneLogin website link: https://github.com/onelogin/openid-connect-dotnet-core-sample

I added http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc as a Redirect URI and it seemed to work.

However, once I am routed to OneLogin and enter my username and password I am brought to this error page...

Generated Error Page dotnet Unhandled Exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jot89.png)

Here is a copy of my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSingleton<IDBService, DBService>();

            // Allow sign in via an OpenId Connect provider like OneLogin
            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = //private; pulling client id from settings
                options.ClientSecret = //private; pulling secret from settings
                options.Authority = //private; endpoint is company based onelogin
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            }
            );
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

I'm puzzled. Because on the OneLogin side I'm getting all Success's from the sign in but when it routes back to my app in http://localhost:5000 I'm getting that error. Any help would be greatly appreciated I've been stumped on this for awhile. Also, the URL at the top of the error page is http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc

Comment: Try `options.ClientSecret = "secret";`

Comment: Does the clientid in your user secrets match the definition in OneLogin?

Answer (score 4):

The Issue has been resolved. It was actually on the OneLogin side not in the .Net code. When setting up your app in OneLogin with .Net be sure to change the Token Endpoint Autheintication Method to be POST instead of the default Basic. Was able to get online with OneLogin and figure it out in about 15min. And that is stated in the .Net example I posted as well. There was a communication issue because I am not actually setting up the OneLogin for this app.